# jQuery blur() not working for Bootstrap navbar toggle on mobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, blur

I have a navbar toggle button in Bootstrap which actually opens left slide menu. I removed navbar content and moved the button to the left for it to serve as a side menu toggler.

```
<a href="#side-menu">
    <button id="menu-button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</a>
```

After clicking or touching this button remains focused which is a bit bad-looking. I used jQuery .Blur() method, but it works only for desktop, not for Android. My webpage is [raigle.com/b.php](http://raigle.com/b.php).

```
$('#menu-button').focus(function() {
    $('#menu-button').blur();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restyle: `.navbar-toggle:focus` in a seperate css that is included after bootstrap css

```
.navbar-toggle:focus {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

or:

replace `.navbar-toggle:focus`  with `.navbar-toggle:active` in the css file then it is OK..

Comment: Worked! I had to change it to the navbar background color, which is rgb(248, 248, 248).

Comment: Glad I helped.. First is better since it doesnt require original bootstrap css file change..